# Add confirmation page to upload script

Tags: php

Can someone show me how to add a confirmation page instead of a line of text in the PHP script after the upload is complete?

here is my current code:

```
<?php 
$target = "upload/"; 
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ; 
$ok=1; 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
{
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded";
} 
else {
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//upload.php

```
<?php 
$target = "upload/"; 
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ; 
$ok=1; 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
{
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " is ready to be uploaded. <a href='confirm.php?confirm=1&filename=". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). "'>Confirm to add your file into our system</a> or <a href='confirm.php?confirm=0&filename=". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). "'>Reverse upload</a>";
} 
else {
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}
?>
```

//confirm.php

```
<?php
if ($_GET['confirm'])
{
    echo "Your file (".$_GET['filename'].") has been uploaded";
    die();
}

echo "Your upload was reverted";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a new `confirmation.php` file and then redirect if file uploaded successfully.

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
{
header("location: confirmation.php");
} 
else {
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}
```

Hope it will help you.

cheers..!!